My room gets stuffy and hot
I'm in a small bedroom and as soon as it gets hot, the room instantly gets stuffy. Even my 2 fans and opening the window, doesn't barely help. I'm gonna get an ac soon, so will that help? Any tips?

What's your question, exactly? Of course an air conditioner will help. What are you asking? Please revise to be more clear.

Heating or cooling is not a cure for stuffiness. The cure is movement of air and refreshing it from elsewhere, preferably outside.  Have a look at a ventilation system or a HRV system (Heat Recovery Ventilation).  If you have access to the roof space, then you could possibly install it yourself.  There are various versions and sizes around.

You might be helped just as much with just a dehumidifier. That turns the heat into a drier heat. Also clean every fabric object (sheets, mattress, your closet) in the room, there might be smells in there that contribute to the stuffyness.
Just putting a fan in the room churning the air doesn't help much by itself, you want to exchange air with the outside.
You can force a draft by pointing one of the fans to the open window from a few feet away and have another path for the air to come back in.
